# Equal heights for cards displayed as inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble displaying cards. I am coding the website mobile first, and then doing media queries for desktop size. I found that setting up the cards with `display: block;` works the best for mobile, since I have having a lot of trouble with `display:flex;`, and I set up the mobile query as `display: inline-block;`. Unfortunately, for certain screen sizes some cards are longer than others. How do I fix that?

```css
.Services {
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
  text-align: center;
}

.servicesWrapper div {
  display: block;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .servicesWrapper div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(80vw / 3);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="Services" id="services">
  <h2>Our Services</h2>
  <div class="servicesWrapper">
    <div class="servicesCard">
      <a href="pages/services/osteopathy.html">
        <img class="cardImage" src="/img/servicesOsteo.png">
        <div class="cardContent">
          <h1 class="cardHeader">Service 1</h1>
          <p class="cardText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et quaerat itaque sit incidunt galisum vel porro adipisci et rerum esse. </p>
          <button class="cardButton">read more</button>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="servicesCard">
      <a href="pages/services/osteopathy.html">
        <img class="cardImage" src="img/servicesAcu.png">
        <div class="cardContent">
          <h1 class="cardHeader">Service 2</h1>
          <p class="cardText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
          <button class="cardButton">read more</button>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="servicesCard">
      <a href="pages/services/osteopathy.html">
        <img class="cardImage" src="img/servicesDiet.png">
        <div class="cardContent">
          <h1 class="cardHeader">Service 3</h1>
          <p class="cardText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et quaerat itaque sit incidunt galisum vel porro adipisci et rerum esse. </p>
          <button class="cardButton">read more</button>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <button class="servicesButton">Our Prices</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

If I hardcode the height, I solve the problem, but I like my design to be responsive, so I coded the cards widths based on viewport size. I am sure there must be a solution, but I cannot find it!

Comment: grid properties only work when using `display: grid`. In any case, the display grid and display flex will auto-size the card's height in a row to be equal by default. Please post your attempt that failed or isn't working as expected. We cannot fix the working code.

Comment: Thank you for pitching in. This is the code of the attempt that didn't work. In my browser it doesn't work, the longer texted cards show up with a bigger height value when then screen size causes the text to have more lines of text than the other cards.